# "Mosaic to new Raster" just stops working

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, mosaic

I have been using the command "Mosaic to new raster" so far successfully. Now, without changing any option from before, it just doesn't work anymore. It is something it already did: pretending to work, but actually gets stuck until I close it and open it again.

It doesn't fail, it is just still showing it is working, but it has already done after 1 minute. This time it didn't not work like that any longer. I closed the software and it just give me back standard "error".

[image]
[image]

Comment: I would avoid writing raster data to a personal geodatabase. Try writing to a folder and including a ".tif" or ".img" extension. What type of raster data are you using?

Comment: Do you have enough memory available?

Comment: Yes, I have enough memory. I am using ".img", I am actually forced to use ".img" since the command does not work with any other file extension.. I am actually adding any file to my personal gdb... Am I making a mistake?