# Mosaicing thousands of raster files in ArcGIS?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, merge, mosaic

I'm trying to mosaic a very large number of rasters (from 1000 to a maximum of 30000, each one having a very small size, less than 100 kb) into a unique final raster.

I have tried to use the **Mosaic To New Raster** tool available at:

```
ArcToolbox > Raster > Raster Dataset
```

I encounter some issues when I choose the input files from the input folder:

[image]

because I need to wait a huge amount of time before viewing the files *loaded* into the main dialog (I know this is certainly related to my PC performances). Even if, in some cases, I'm able to load all the input files, the duration of the analysis is very long due to the number of the files.

From some comments on [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/153797/mosaic-to-new-raster-just-stops-working) question, it seems that it should be avoided the writing of raster data to a personal geodatabase. I set the Default.gdb for the `Output Location` parameter, but I don't understand very well its role.

Since I'm unfamiliar with ArcGIS, is there a more efficient way for the mosaicing of a large number of input rasters? Any workaround or method for avoiding the overloading of the PC resources?

Comment: This "preliminary loading" is ArcGIS checking *every* image you pass to it to check that it is compatible with the tool.

Comment: Thanks, @Midavalo. So, I imagine I can't avoid it. Do you think it may change something if I set a specific location for writing the output?

Comment: What type of data are you working with?

Comment: @Aaron It's a mosaic of several .asc files covering a whole country. The main issue is not the quality of the output, but the fact that ArcGIS is near to crash if I try to import all the files at the same time. However, if I set an output filename instead of a .gdb as Output Location, it seems to work faster. Since I'm not an expert of ArcGIS, I need to proceed with trial&error :)

Comment: I would avoid writing to a geodatabase and opt for a raster format such as IMG. Also, make sure you have 64 bit background geoprocessing available (Geoprocessing > Geoprocessing Options > Background processing > Enable

Comment: This is a related post: http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/160580/8104

Comment: @Aaron Thanks for the post, but probably your confirmation on my doubt about the writing to a geodatabase could be a good hint. I'll give an update as soon as possible.

Comment: There are many things wrong here. ASCII is the worst possible raster format. 3000 is far too many files to process at one time, much less 30k. I'd mosaic in 4x4 to 8x8 clusters as compressed geoTIFF, then make a mosaic dataset from the remainder (all on an SSD, of course).

Comment: See also http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/176554/processing-time-speed-for-mosaic-to-new-raster/176608#176608

Comment: Thanks, @Vince. The operation you propose is interesting but, since  I haven't a SSD, I'm afraid it could be too much expensive in terms of resources.

Comment: @Aaron I solved by using chunks of data and writing to a raster format instead of a geodatabase, as you suggested. I think it was the key (together with the enabling of the Background processing) so feel free to post your comment as an answer and I'll accept it. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest one of two approaches:

1. Split your mosaic operation into several steps and then mosaic the mosaics.  I've done this before.
2. Build a model in ModelBuilder and use the mosaic tool (not mosaic as new raster) and then copy the raster making sure to overwrite the original name.  This will have the effect of accumulating the values.